# xml deserialization with error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

can you help me?
I have small experience in xml-serialization and can't resolve this problem.
I create request and get an answer 
I have xml-response like this(from debug):

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n
<SpellResult>
<error code=\"1\" pos=\"0\" row=\"0\" col=\"0\" len=\"6\">
    <word>wird</word>
    <s>word</s>
    <s>world</s>
...
</error>
</SpellResult>
```

my deserialization:

```
  ...
var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUtf8ByteArray(response.ToString())))
{
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    var result = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    return result;
}

...
```

Where:

```
private Byte[] StringToUtf8ByteArray(string xmlString)
{
  //  UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
    return byteArray;
}
```

This is T-type:

```
   [Serializable()]
   [XmlRoot("SpellResult")]
    public class SpellResult
    {
      public List<error> Errors
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class error
    {
        [XmlAttribute("code")]
        public int Code
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlAttribute("pos")]
        public int Position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlAttribute("row")]
        public int Row
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

       [XmlAttribute("col")]
        public int Column
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlAttribute("len")]
        public int Length
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlElement("word")]
        public string Word
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlArray]
        [XmlArrayItem("s", typeof(Steer))]

        public Steer[] Steer
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class Steer
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("s")]
        public string s { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have exception: {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}
I tried to fix this problem with any answers from SO and other sites, but they do not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, XML Serialization doesn't use the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To help diagnose errors like this, try to create an instance of the class, containing the data that you expected to get from your input XML. Then *serialize* your instance, and look at the results. This will tell you how XML Serialization *expects* your data to appear.

I suspect that you are missing an `<Errors>` element.

Comment: I agree, the List<error> does not use xmlarray or xmlarrayitem tags like the steer[]

Answer (score 0):

You class hierarchy, if you want to have `Steer` as class, must looks like this:

```
public class SpellResult
{
  [XmlElement("error")]
  public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("pos")]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("row")]
    public int Row { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("col")]
    public int Column { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("len")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("word")]
    public string Word { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("s")]
    public List<Steer> Steers { get; set; }

}

public class Steer
{
    [XmlText]
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

or, you can avoid class `Steer` just deserialize `s` elements into list of strings

```
[XmlElement("s")]
public List<string> Steers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh,
It was my carelessness and simple mistake.
I wrote

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responce))
```

But responce is an object of RestResponse...
Where I wrote:

```
string resp = response.Content.ToString();
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp)))
{
    ... 
}
```

It's worked. Facepalm.

Thanks for help.